# Navigating back and forth not working

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

hi i created an app which contains  three pages,
if go from MainPage to Page1 and reversely 3 to 4 times it ts working fine, but when i Navigate from Mainpage to Page 2 it is working but  when i navigate back from Page 2 to Main Page it is opening MainPage after 1 second it is going back to Page2

can you please tell me the solution for this

Comment: Please provide some code. Without it, it is very hard to help.

Comment: there is no code for this, actually windows phone back button handles it defaultly

Comment: Is this in the emulator or on a real device? Sounds like the back button is stuck at times.

Comment: *it is opening MainPage after 1 second it is going back to Page2*

It doesn't sounds like normal behavior. Can you share sample?

Comment: it sounds like rendering problem

Comment: i cant say for sure, but something in your page2 is causing this for example maybe if you have more than 2 listboxes. do you have ApplicationBar in your page?... or something in you MainPage is reloading, for example in Loaded event or OnNavigatedTo, this is pure guess, that's why we need to see your code

Answer (score 1):

Okay i am going to give this a wild guess seeing that you have not given code ,
on each page there is a override method you can use, onNavigatedTo.

what i will do is put an [OnNavigatedTo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.page.onnavigatedto%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) event on each page and put a break point in that event and step to see what each individual page does, here is a quick example where i use onnavigated to test if the navigation to this page was a 'back' navigation!

```
     protected async override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
        {
            //Check if navigation was back!
            // you can add the breakpoint here if you want to.

            if (e.NavigationMode == NavigationMode.Back)
            {
                messagebox.show("Nav is back!");
            }
```

now you can easily see what each individual page does when navigated to :) hope this helps a bit.

Comment: Async is not needed in this sample, but in general i agree :)

Comment: Prathep: Put Arrie's code into the main page. Navigate back and forth. Now whenever you navigate back, a message box is shown, correct?

Comment: @VitaliiVasylenko the async is there becaus i have an awaited call after the check, but yes it is not needed :)